# In ios 8 push notification not showing me badges for current app

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ios7, push-notification

Hello friends i am new in push notification please help me out.
I am trying to get badge count for my app but "NSDictionary userInfo" contains only alert and sound .
this is the code for register device for push notification

```
  -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |  UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Now
When i get message from server.

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {

        /***********code to show alert********/
        if (![[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"alert"]] isEqualToString:@""] && [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"alert"]]!=nil)
        {
            NSString *MSG =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"alert"]];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:MSG delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }

        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Notification Received." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber =[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badge"]integerValue];

    if (userInfo)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);

        if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"])
        {
            if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badgecount"])
            {
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badgecount"] intValue];
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Now output is

```
{ aps =     
    {
        alert = "MAgic 2 SAlon App!";
        sound = default;
    };
}
```

my php code is
    `

```
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'xxxxxxxxx';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'xxxxxx';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'xxxxxxx!'; 

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
 $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n',  strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no problem with your iOS code so far, but in your php script you are missing the badge count.**

---

*In all iOS apps, unread notification counts are maintained from backend/server. When the backend/server sends a push notification to a particular device then server sends the badge count along with the payload.*

So I guess the back end is not sending you the badge count.

The backend/server team should follow this format, so that you can get badge count programatically:-

```
{
    "aps" :  
    {
        "alert" : "msg",
        "badge" : 1 ,
        "sound" : "demo.aiff"
    }
}
```

**Here are tutorial link, how to add badge count in php Script:-**

http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/ios-push-notifications-in-php/

http://learn-php-by-example.blogspot.in/2013/01/working-with-apple-push-notification.html

Comment: plz tell me how can i get badge count .i want to display that on app icon .thank you for your help

Comment: now i know that that payload is not sending any badge

Comment: but can you tell me how to send badge in pay load

Comment: It's very easy I guess to add badge count in your php script. Why are you are not following the tutorials available after that  if you still don't get badge count then post a question. @user3189586